# Why is the storage of Applications showing incorrectly in mac?

Tags: mac, finder, hard-drive, applications, storage

[image]

I've had problems regarding my storage on the HDD recently. The applications total shows up as 56GB but all the distribution that I can find is this (in the image). Where else is that remaining 40+ GB going? Even the documents only shows 2gb worth of files.
I reindexed the whole Drive on Spotlight a while ago. Please help

Comment: What 40GB are you referring to?  What are expecting these numbers to add up to?

Comment: Is this the same problem? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/452264